# Import package from user created JAR file

Tags: java, jar, javac

I have two files; `Beta.java`:

```
package beta;
public class Beta { }
```

and `Gamma.java`:

```
package gamma;
import beta.*;
public class Gamma { }
```

I create a JAR archive using `jar cvf b.jar Beta.class`, yet when I try to compile with `javac -cp b.jar Gamma.java` I get:

```
Gamma.java:2: error: package beta does not exist
import beta.*;
^
1 error
```

I know I can just run `javac *.java`, but I want to be able to access `Beta.class` from  a JAR file for portability. This is an very basic question, but I still have had a lot of trouble trying to solve it. Thanks.

Comment: Beta.class needs to be in the beta directory. try `jar cvf b.jar beta\Beta.class`

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks.
I forgot that the package structure has to mirrored in the directory structure.